# Finding majority element in an array ( getting wrong output for particular cases with long integer input)

Tags: c++, output

I was solving a Majority_element problem, where I would be provided an int 'n' followed by an array whose size is n, as input. If any element's frequency in the array is more than n/2, then return 1, otherwise, return 0. Now, my program works correctly for small values of integer elements, but it's giving a false output for bigger int values.

**Here's the source code**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int get_majority_element(vector<int> &a) {
  int count{};
  std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());
  for( size_t i{}; i<a.size() ; ++i ){         //counter
    for( size_t j = i+1 ; j<a.size() ; ++j ){
      if( a.at(i) == a.at(j) ){
        count += 1;  // may have to inclue a count nullifier if two elements are repeated
      }
    }
  }
  if( count > ( a.size()/2 ) ){
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;  
  }

}

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<int> a(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    std::cin >> a.at(i);
  }
  std::cout << get_majority_element(a) << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

**Here are some outputs**

6

1 1 1 2 3 4

0

---

6

1 1 1 1 2 3

1

---

10

512766168 717383758 5 126144732 5 573799007 5 5 5 405079772

1 ( should be 0)

---

Now could somebody please explain to me what's going wrong? I even tried setting vector data type to long long to prevent potential memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do,

- you don't need `std::sort`.
- you need to reset `count`.
- check should be done in outer loop

```
bool get_majority_element(const vector<int> &a) {
  for (size_t i{}; i < a.size() ; ++i) {
    int count{};
    for (size_t j = i+1 ; j<a.size() ; ++j) {
      if (a.at(i) == a.at(j)){
        count += 1;
      }
    }
    if (count > ( a.size()/2 )) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;  
}
```

or

```
bool get_majority_element(const vector<int> &a) {
    for (size_t i{}; i < a.size() ; ++i) {
        if (std::count(a.begin() + i, a.end(), a[i]) > a.size() / 2) {
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;  
}
```

Complexity: `O(n²)`.

Once sorted, equal elements are adjacent, so you don't need to check each element:

```
bool get_majority_element(vector<int> &a) {
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());

    for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); /*empty*/) {
        auto next = std::find_if(it, a.end(), [&](int n){ return n != *it; });

        if (std::distance(it, next) > a.size() / 2) {
            return true;
        }
        it = next;
    }
    return false;  
}
```

Complexity: `O(n lon n)`.

For info, there exist also an algorithm to do it linearly which consist to find possible candidate, and then check it.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your algo, but the problem now is that I don't understand what is wrong with my code? If Ihave to change my code, then I should learn my mistake first. It would be great if you could help me with that :)

Comment: What should `count` represent in your algorithm? What does it compute actually?

Comment: Count calculates the number of times an element is repeated, or say the frequency of the element in the array.

Comment: That is what you expected. But you compute `count` for the whole vector (without reset it), so you count **all** equal pairs. `{1, 1, 2, 2}` result in 2. Whereas you expect 1 then 0 then 1 then 0.

Comment: @SudhanshuShekhar You got lucky your first 2 trials works, as they actually equal to `2+1` and `3+2+1` respectably. And your third trial is actually `4+3+2+1`

Comment: @SudhanshuShekhar Try print out `a.at(i)` and `a.at(j)` inside the `if(a.at(i) == a.at(j))` and you will notice the problem